# How to obtain names of only files in a directory which match a certain naming pattern, and ignore others, in python?

Tags: python, string, directory, path, filenames

I have a directory full of jpeg files, which should all be named according to the same format, and might look like this for example:

```
"ABC_00001_D0.jpg"
"ABC_00100_D8.jpg"
"ABC_00023_D4.jpg"
...
```

where the numeric characters can be any number, but the letters and underscores should always be the same for every filename, and in the same positions.

I am reading the filenames into a list, while making sure to only grab the jpg types like this:

```python
import os

expected_filename_style = "ABC_00000_D0.jpg"

folder_path = r"C:\my_dir"
filelist = []
for f in os.listdir(folder_path):
    if f.endswith(".jpg"):
        filelist.append(f)
        print(f)
```

However, sometimes there will be a rogue filename in the directory which doesn't follow my naming convention. For example, I would like to ignore a filenames which look like `EFG_00001_D1.jpg` or `ABC_0E001_D0.jpg`.

I would like the ability to change the expected format (for example to "00_XYZ_00.jpg) and the code should now accept the new format. However, it will always be only numeric characters which are allowed to vary, so I suppose want to check that the non-numeric characters in each filename match the non-numeric ones at the correct positions in `expected_filename_style` somehow? Can anyone help me solve this problem?

Comment: Use re library with regex `re.compile("ABC_(\d+)_D(\d+).jpg", flags=re.I)`.

Comment: Your suggestion does not take my *expected_filename_style*  variable as an input. What if I want to change this, as stated?

Comment: Then you change your regexp accordingly. I dont think that it is difficult to create a dynamic regexp depending on the input

Comment: Can you provide a small working example? I am new to python and just learning.

Comment: I'll add an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in comments, here is a solution using re library

```
import re
expected_file_format = "ABC_00000_D0.jpg"

# as mentioned, this can vary. 
# Also, characters and underscore represent themselves, 
# but 0 represents all digits 0-9

regex = re.compile(expected_file_format.replace("0", "\d") + "$", flags=re.I) 
# dont add the flags if you want case sensitive match

file_name = "ABC_12345_D9.jpg"
print(bool(regex.match(file_name)))  # True

file_name = "ABC_1234_D9.jpg"
print(bool(regex.match(file_name)))  # False
```

Comment: It seems like I also don't need the *.endswith()* anymore either.

Comment: Yes .match is used for searching from beginning of the string, and "$" implies match till end of string. So "ABC_12345_D6.jpge"  will fail the search